# Unable to increase replica count in openshift deployment templates

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, openshift

I am trying to deploy `mysql` cluster on `openshift` with one master and 2 slaves replicas this [MySQL-Replication-Example](https://github.com/praiskup/openshift-mysql/blob/master/5.6/examples/replica/mysql_replica.json).
I changed the image used in this json template by the latest image and changed the slave replica count to 2 at line 244. It deployed successfully initially.
After some time, I got following errors:

```
2020-05-07T10:34:57.974142Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2020-05-07T10:34:57.974208Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
```

As per my understanding and investigation, it works fine for single slave replica, but fails for two slave replicas which is a mandatory requirement for me. I cannot kill any slave process.

I am new to the `openshift`.
What should I change so that it works fine for two slave replicas too?

Comment: Perhaps @HonzaHorak  could shed some light on this.

Comment: Also, @MartinNagy can guide for the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The [MYSQL Example](https://github.com/praiskup/openshift-mysql/blob/master/5.6/examples/replica/mysql_replica.json#L62) has a [Persistent Volume Claim](https://github.com/praiskup/openshift-mysql/blob/master/5.6/examples/replica/mysql_replica.json#L55) with the Access Mode as type `ReadWriteOnce`. You can change this to `ReadWriteMany`. However, you should look at the [Access Modes](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.4/storage/understanding-persistent-storage.html#pv-access-modes_understanding-persistent-storage) documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for responding. In my opinion, Access Mode for PVC is not the problem. I have seen many replication examples where `ReadWriteOnce` is used only. Also, I tried deploying after suggested change but the issue is still occurring.

Comment: What is kind of backing storage are you using? What does your OpenShift master, infra and app nodes look like?